# Is it possible to redistribute the 5 TB of space that I have on organization emails on the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Every time that I create a new organization email on Google Cloud Platform, it comes with 5TB of space available for this email... The problem that I see with it is that no one in the company uses all this available space. Is there any way of redistributing this space among different accounts? As an example, let's say I have 5 organization emails on Google Cloud Platform, each one of them has 5TB of space, I'd like to limit the space of four of these emails to 1TB and put the extra space on one single email, so that would be 4TB left * 4 emails + 5TB = 21TB. This way I would have four emails with 1TB and one email with 21TB available on Google Drive. Is it possible to do on the Google Cloud Platform? Do I have this kind of control somehow?

Comment: I don't know for sure but, it shouldn't be possible because you would be able to cheat the system. The idea is that you need more space and have to buy it. The same is with google drive. You get 15GB for free, but if you want more you need to pay.

Comment: @PredragDj I understand that... But each organization email is already paid, I need to pay more $5 for each one of them. So that wouldn't be exactly like cheating since I'm already paying for this space indirectly...

Comment: I understand. There must be some support service where you can find out for sure if it is possible. Hope someone will help you

Comment: It is not possible, you do not have any control over it, but you can always try to contact the sales if they can make an exemption.